# dispatch_async in return method Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have been trying to use `dispatch_async` in a method that returns a result. However, I observed that the method returns before executing the `dispatch_async` block. Due to this I'm not getting the results I expect. Here is some code that demonstrates my problem.

```
-(BOOL) isContactExists {
    BOOL isContactExistsInXYZ = YES;
    UserId *userId = contact.userId;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        iOSContact *contact = [iOSContact contactForUserId:userId];
        if (nil == contact)
        {
          isContactExistsInXYZ = NO;
        }
    });    

    return isContactExistsInXYZ;
}
```

This method `isContactExists` is called somewhere else and based on the response from that method I have to do some stuff. But every time, the value of `isContactExistsInXYZ` is not what I expect. How do I handle `dispatch_async` in this situation?

Comment: dispatch_async is asynchronous it's mean that yhe return will be reached before the end of the dispatch async

Comment: @francescu,That I understood with my analysis can you please help to how to handle it in other way, a code snippet or logical information. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

If your going the block route your method needs to look something like this.

```
- (void)isContactExistsWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL exists)) completion 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        BOOL isContactExistsInXYZ = YES;
        UserId *userId = contact.userId;
        iOSContact *contact = [iOSContact contactForUserId:userId];
        if (nil == contact)
        {
          isContactExistsInXYZ = NO;
        }
        completion(isContactExistsInXYZ);
    });
}
```

And where you are calling it something like this.

```
[someObject isContactExistsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL exists) {
    // do something with your BOOL
}];
```

You should also consider placing your heavy operations in a other que than main. Like this.

```
- (void)isContactExistsWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL exists)) completion 
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^
    {
        BOOL isContactExistsInXYZ = YES;
        UserId *userId = contact.userId;
        iOSContact *contact = [iOSContact contactForUserId:userId];
        if (nil == contact)
        {
          isContactExistsInXYZ = NO;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            completion(isContactExistsInXYZ);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to respect that what you are trying to do is asynchronous and embrace that. This means not using a return value. Instead you can write your method to take a callback block as a parameter. Then, when your asynchronous check is complete you can call the block with the result.

---

So your method signature would become:

```
- (void)checkIfContactExistsWithCompletion:(ContactExistsBlock)completion {
```

Where `ContactExistsBlock` is a block definition with no return and probably a single `BOOL` parameter.

```
typedef void (^ContactExistsBlock) (BOOL exists);
```

Comment: Can u elaborate with a sample code or are you saying me to use "completion handler" block

Answer (score 3):

The reason is `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^`does not wait until execution is done. You are probably messing up stuff there. Normally, this is used to update UI asynchronously along with other server content getting downloaded in some other thread. Try using  `dispatch_sync` instead.

Comment: Here one thing I have to mention is that my requirement is that I have to run the operation in background thread, so I chosen to use `dispatch_async` over `dispatch_sync`. Can you please get me a logical information or to handle the same in other way. Thanks.

Comment: You need to look into delegation pattern. There are plenty of examples in iOS framework. See how NSConnection works. It gives you a call back as soon as some data chunk is ready. So, probably, you need to perform your operation asynchronously and then handle the call back through delegate methods.